# I was written this code in pycharm but it gives error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytrends'"

Tags: pycharm

```py
from pytrends.request import TrendReq

pytrend = TrendReq()
trend_search = pytrend.trending_searches(pn = 'united_states')
print(trend_search)
```

I want to know if PyCharm supports those libraries.

Comment: did you install the module with `pip install pytrends` ?

Comment: You have t install them first. Your IDE is not automatically installing all the possible external libraries

Answer (score 0):

pycharm does not need to support some library `x` in particular. What it needs to do (and it already does it) is to support choosing the python interpreter you want to use. Go to `File -> Settings...` and in the window that opens, go to "Project: <your_project>" and then "Python Interpreter". You can see and change which python interpreter your project is using.

You can use the system python interpreter (not a good choice), a python interpreter in a virtual environment, or a python interpreter in a conda environment. You just need to make sure that the pytrends library is actually installed in the specific environment your project is using in pycharm. You can even use the GUI in pycharm where you choose your project interpreter to install new libraries.